# Does Django implement user permissions in databases with models?

Tags: python, django, orm, django-admin

In a typical database, admin can assign users and can create tables which can be accessed by only a particular set of users or groups. One can also create queries that can be made by certain users in a database like MySQL.

Does Django provide any such functionality or is is it only the Django ADMIN Interface that does this?

I am aware that the admin can create users and provide them with permissions for working with app models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django by itself doesn't provide access to the database-level users / groups / permissions, because it doesn't make much sense for a typical web application where all connections will be made with the same database user (the one defined in `settings.DATABASES`). Note that it's not a shortcoming be really the standard for web applications.

What Django provides is application-level users / groups / permissions (cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/). You have access to this application-level layer thru the admin but also - of course - programmatically thru the `django.contrib.auth` package.

Comment: Hey @brunodesthuilliers, Thanks for the info. My follow up question is about how django translates the user permissions in the admin interface on the models to the database level. I know that it uses Object Relational Mapping for converting models to tables in a database.

Comment: @susheel Django is OSS so you can check by yourself how `django.contrib.auth` is implemented.  Quick answer: it's all based on models for users, groups, permissions and the relationships between them.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do that.

Django defined these models in module `django.contrib.auth.models`

You can import all models from there like Group, Permission and all.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import *
```

If you want to list all django auth models you can see them in mysql/or other database too by prefix auth_* e.g, in mysql

```
show tables like "%auth%";
```

Over these models you can use django ORM.

Comment: @vaibav-kumar I think the OP was asking about database level users and permissions, not application level.